# Excel Macro Filter by over x days

Tags: excel, vba

Issue: I can filter by `Criteria1` but on `Criteria2` I want only to have those that are filtered by `Criteria1` and over 89 days.

Code:

```
  Sub Reset_Table()
    '
    ' Reset_Table Macro
    '
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$39:$I$14625").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "First namefilter", "Somethingelse", _

    Operator:=xlFilterValues

            'Over 90 days

               ActiveSheet.Range("$B$39:$I$14625").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria2:=Array(">89"), Operator:=xlFilterValues                  
    End Sub
```

Comment: When you use the *Recorder*, what do you get??

Comment: "Method of range class failed"

Comment: `Criteria2` is only used when you are apply two criterias at once to the same field. The second filter on field 6 should be another `Criteria1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx), `Criteria2` is only used when you are apply two criterias at once to the same field. The second filter on field 6 should be another `Criteria1`.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
    with .Range("$B$39:$I$14625")
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("First namefilter", "Somethingelse", "everything"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">89"
    end with
end with
```